# Using SASS to extend selectors with elements

Tags: sass

I'm working on an SCSS stylesheet, and I have a rule that looks something like this:

```
.footer-link-row {
    color: red;
    ul& {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

I want the `ul&` line compile to the selector `ul.footer-link-row`. However, this selector returns a compiler error, and using a `&ul` compiles to `.footer-link-row ul`. What's the correct way to select something like this?

--Added--
To clarify, the eventual CSS I want out of this is:

```
.footer-link-row {
    color: red;
}
ul.footer-link-row {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like the following:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  .footer-link-row {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

The ampersand is used to require that both selectors match

```
a { text-decoration: none;
  &:hover { border-width: 1px }
}
// compiles to 
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

If you want the ul.footer-link-row try

```
ul {
  &.footer-link-row {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .footer-link-row {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Your clarification indicates that you need two scopes.

```
ul {
  &.footer-link-row {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.footer-link-row {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want... I don't want `padding: 0;` to apply to all `ul`'s, just `ul`'s that have the class `footer-link-row`.

Comment: I think you're going to need separate nesting for the ul:.footer-link-row.  Maybe that needs to be outside the scope of the ul{}, but it'll depend on your markup.